# Kotlin: Construct value of derived generic type in base class

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to reduce duplication across some vector types by defining the operators once, but I'm not sure it's possible. This seemed like the most promising approach:

```
open class VecN<Derived: VecN<Derived>>(val buffer: FloatArray) {
    operator fun minus(other: Derived) = Derived(buffer.zip(other.buffer, { a, b -> a - b }).toFloatArray())
    operator fun plus(other: Derived) = Derived(buffer.zip(other.buffer, { a, b -> a + b }).toFloatArray())
    ... many more operators...
}

class Vec2(x: Float, y: Float) : VecN<Vec2>(floatArrayOf(x, y))
class Vec3(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float) : VecN<Vec3>(floatArrayOf(x, y, z))
class Vec4(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float, w: Float) : VecN<Vec4>(floatArrayOf(x, y, z, w))
```

This gives me "Type parameter Derived cannot be called as function" where I try to construct my Derived return value.

Is it possible to achieve this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that in a straightforward way because, in Kotlin, you can only call a constructor of a concrete type, there's no way to call a constructor of a type parameter. Moreover, Kotlin does not allow passing an array into a function/constructor that expects fixed number of separate values.

However, you can try to achieve that without too much boilerplate using an abstract function, like this:

```
abstract class VecN<Derived: VecN<Derived>>(val buffer: FloatArray) {
    protected abstract fun createNew(buffer: FloatArray): Derived 

    operator fun minus(other: Derived) = 
        createNew(buffer.zip(other.buffer, Float::minus).toFloatArray())

    // ...
}
```

Then you have to override this function in each of the derived classes:

```
class Vec2(x: Float, y: Float) : VecN<Vec2>(floatArrayOf(x, y)) {
    override protected fun createNew(buffer: FloatArray) = Vec2(buffer[0], buffer[1])
}
```

[(demo of this code)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/fg11123prnpdnab6bk1fig31i8/l5odolj7hcpacclgp67tarete5)

Comment: Thanks: That's done the trick. The `Float::minus` is nice too. (The lack of a constructor taking an array was a copy/paste oversight.)